# SWF file not working in all paths

Tags: actionscript-3

i did a flash project and it is working fine in the compiler path.
when i open the SWF file, it works fine.

but if i copy all the files to another path, it is not working!
kindly help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update Global Security Settings panel: add your new folder location

http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04.html